# MacPherson strut not alligned to spring

Tags: suspension, springs

After new spring installation, I noticed the spring is not parallel to strut.

Instead it is in an angle. What's wrong?

Comment: Did you install the spring? Did you seat it correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Can you add a photo here to help understand exactly what you mean

Answer (score 3):

What @HandyHowie said in comments. Of the two ends of the spring, one spring will be relatively flat and the other end not. The end which is not flat will fit into a pocket on the mount. I believe this is *usually* the bottom of the spring. I believe this is done to prevent the spring from continually rotating.

You can see how in the image, the right hand mount has a pocket right at the front. This is the "pocket" I'm talking about. If you don't put the spring into this pocket correctly, it won't sit right and can be off. (NOTE: This may not be what your mounts look like, but should give you an idea what I'm talking about.)

[image]